# WPF(MVVM) + Entity Framework: обновление GUI с изменением навигационного свойства

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, mvvm

Допустим в приложении MVVM в модели есть два класса:

```
public class Author
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Book> Books { get; set; }
}

public class Book
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int AuthorId { get; set; }
    public virtual Author Author { get; set; }
}
```

Во ViewModel есть класс, в который параметром передается какой-нибудь автор с несколькими книгами, загруженный из БД средствами EntityFramework:

```
public class AuthorsViewModel: ViewModelBase
{

    public AuthorsViewModel()
        : this(null)
    {  

    }

    public AuthorsViewModel(Author author)
    {
        _author = author;
    }  

    Author _author;
    public Author CurrentAuthor
    {
        get
        {
            if (_author == null)
            {
                _author = new Author();
            }
            return _author;
        }
        set
        {
            _author = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("CurrentAuthor");
        }
    }

    Book _selectedBook;
    public Book SelectedBook
    {
        get
        {
            if (_selectedBook == null)
            {
                _selectedBook = new Book();
            }
            return _selectedBook;
        }
        set
        {
            _selectedBook = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedBook");
        }
    }   

    public RelayCommand RemoveBookCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return new RelayCommand(RemoveBook);
        }
    }
    void RemoveBook()
    {
        CurrentAuthor.Books.Remove(SelectedBook);
    }      
}
```

И, наконец, во View есть окно, в котором этот автор подробно расписан:

```
<Window x:Class="{КЛАСС ОКНА}"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="{НАШ NAMESPACE}"
        xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:{ТАМ ЛЕЖИТ НАШ КЛАСС ViewModel}"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="" Height="246" Width="300">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <vm:AuthorsViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Text="Author:"/>
        <TextBox 
            Text="{Binding Path=CurrentAuthor.Name}" 
            Width="150"
            Height="23"
            Margin="40,0,0,0" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
            VerticalAlignment="Top" 
            BorderBrush="Black"/>
        <ListView
            BorderBrush="Black"
            Width="250"
            Height="150"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Path=CurrentAuthor.Books}"
            SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedBook}">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn 
                        Header="Books"
                        DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Title}"/>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
        <Button
            Content="Remove book"
            Height="25"
            Width="50"
            VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
            Margin="5"
            Command="{Binding Path=RemoveBookCommand}"/> 
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Все это вроде бы работает, но только при нажатии на кнопку удаления текущая книга действительно удаляется из сущности, но вот в окне она по прежнему продолжает отображаться. Как при изменении навигационного свойства CurrentAuthor.Books обновлять пользовательский интерфейс?

P.S.: Пример полностью абстрактный, но код в целом повторяет логику работы моего приложения, так что если есть замечания - буду рад услышать.

Answer (score 4):

Для того, чтобы воспользоваться прокси-колекцией `Collection<T>` вам все же придется внести корректировки в модель. Ваша коллекция книг должна реализовывать интерфейс `IList<Book>`, например:

```
public virtual List<Book> Books { get; set; } = new List<Book>();
```

Больше никаких изменений в модель мы вносить не будем.

Для того, чтобы ваш UI получал уведомления при изменении содержимого коллекции книг - удалении, вставке и т. п., нам необходимо реализовать интерфейс `INotifyCollectionChanged`. Реализация его нетривиальна, но, к счастью, в стандартной библиотеке есть (по крайней мере) один пример реализации - это класс `ObservableCollection<T>`: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system/compmod/system/collections/objectmodel/observablecollection.cs
Как видно в исходном коде класс наследуется от прокси-коллекции `Collection<T>`, но, по неизвестным причинам, разработчики скрыли от нас прокси функционал.
Чтож, я просто скоприровал реализацию `ObservableCollection<T>` и вместо существующих конструкторов написал свои:

```
public class ProxyObservableCollection<T> : Collection<T>, INotifyCollectionChanged, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ProxyObservableCollection() : base() { }

    public ProxyObservableCollection(IEnumerable<T> collection)
    {
        if (collection == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("collection");

        CopyFrom(collection);
    }

    public ProxyObservableCollection(IList<T> list) : base(list) { }
```

Особый интерес предоставляет здесь последний конструктор - он-то как раз (в отличие от копирующего конструктора) и создает прокси на передаваемый `IList<T>`.

Теперь этим можно воспользоваться. Добавим в VM:

```
ProxyObservableCollection<Book> _booksOfCurrentAuthor;
public ProxyObservableCollection<Book> BooksOfCurrentAuthor
{
    get
    {
        return _booksOfCurrentAuthor;
    }
    private set
    {
        _booksOfCurrentAuthor = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(BooksOfCurrentAuthor));
    }
}
```

Добавим в свойство `CurrentAuthor`:

```
public Author CurrentAuthor
{
    get
    {
        ...
    }
    set
    {
        _author = value;
        BooksOfCurrentAuthor = new ProxyObservableCollection(CurrentAuthor.Books);
        RaisePropertyChanged("CurrentAuthor");
    }
```

Теперь копия коллекции создаваться не будет, но, в то же время, все изменения в коллекции книг будут оповещать UI:

```
    <ListView
        ...
        ItemsSource="{Binding Path=BooksOfCurrentAuthor}"
```

На всякий случай привожу полный код `ProxyObservableCollection<T>`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace MyNamespace
{
    public class ProxyObservableCollection<T> : Collection<T>, INotifyCollectionChanged, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public ProxyObservableCollection() : base() { }

        public ProxyObservableCollection(IEnumerable<T> collection)
        {
            if (collection == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("collection");

            CopyFrom(collection);
        }

        public ProxyObservableCollection(IList<T> list) : base(list) { }

        private void CopyFrom(IEnumerable<T> collection)
        {
            IList<T> items = Items;
            if (collection != null && items != null)
            {
                using (IEnumerator<T> enumerator = collection.GetEnumerator())
                {
                    while (enumerator.MoveNext())
                    {
                        items.Add(enumerator.Current);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public void Move(int oldIndex, int newIndex)
        {
            MoveItem(oldIndex, newIndex);
        }

        event PropertyChangedEventHandler INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged
        {
            add
            {
                PropertyChanged += value;
            }
            remove
            {
                PropertyChanged -= value;
            }
        }

        public virtual event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged;

        protected override void ClearItems()
        {
            CheckReentrancy();
            base.ClearItems();
            OnPropertyChanged(CountString);
            OnPropertyChanged(IndexerName);
            OnCollectionReset();
        }

        protected override void RemoveItem(int index)
        {
            CheckReentrancy();
            T removedItem = this[index];

            base.RemoveItem(index);

            OnPropertyChanged(CountString);
            OnPropertyChanged(IndexerName);
            OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove, removedItem, index);
        }

        protected override void InsertItem(int index, T item)
        {
            CheckReentrancy();
            base.InsertItem(index, item);

            OnPropertyChanged(CountString);
            OnPropertyChanged(IndexerName);
            OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add, item, index);
        }

        protected override void SetItem(int index, T item)
        {
            CheckReentrancy();
            T originalItem = this[index];
            base.SetItem(index, item);

            OnPropertyChanged(IndexerName);
            OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace, originalItem, item, index);
        }

        protected virtual void MoveItem(int oldIndex, int newIndex)
        {
            CheckReentrancy();

            T removedItem = this[oldIndex];

            base.RemoveItem(oldIndex);
            base.InsertItem(newIndex, removedItem);

            OnPropertyChanged(IndexerName);
            OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Move, removedItem, newIndex, oldIndex);
        }

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
            => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, e);

        protected virtual event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (CollectionChanged != null)
            {
                using (BlockReentrancy())
                {
                    CollectionChanged(this, e);
                }
            }
        }

        protected IDisposable BlockReentrancy()
        {
            _monitor.Enter();
            return _monitor;
        }

        protected void CheckReentrancy()
        {
            if (_monitor.Busy)
            {
                if ((CollectionChanged != null) && (CollectionChanged.GetInvocationList().Length > 1))
                    throw new InvalidOperationException();
            }
        }

        private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
            => OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));

        private void OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedAction action, object item, int index)
            => OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(action, item, index));

        private void OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedAction action, object item, int index, int oldIndex)
            => OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(action, item, index, oldIndex));

        private void OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedAction action, object oldItem, object newItem, int index)
            => OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(action, newItem, oldItem, index));

        private void OnCollectionReset()
            => OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));

        private class SimpleMonitor : IDisposable
        {
            public void Enter()
            {
                ++_busyCount;
            }

            public void Dispose()
            {
                --_busyCount;
            }

            public bool Busy { get { return _busyCount > 0; } }

            int _busyCount;
        }

        private const string CountString = "Count";

        private const string IndexerName = "Item[]";

        private SimpleMonitor _monitor = new SimpleMonitor();
    }
}
```

Comment: @VladD, перелогиньтесь.

Comment: @Other, спасибо за комплимент, но, к сожалению, я не VladD )

Comment: Я-то знаю правду™, создаёшь видимость конкуренции, @VladD? :)

Comment: @Андрей к чему это "к сожалению"? Никогда не сожалейте о том, что вы не кто-то другой.

Answer (score 2):

Для того, чтобы ваши изменения коллекции были видны в представлении нужно использовать тип [ObservableCollection{T}](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604(v=vs.100).aspx). Т.е. ваша модель будет выглядеть следующим образом:

```
public class Author
{
    ...
    public virtual ObservableCollection<Book> Books { get; set; }
}
```

Если не хотите менять модель, то вам придется завести такую коллекцию в модели представления, привязаться к ней и следить за тем, чтобы содержимое коллекции в модели представления всегда совпадало с содержимым коллекции модели.