# Ссылка ObservableCollection на List - возможна?

Tags: c#, .net

Вот рабочий пример:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<string> a = new List<string>();
    List<string> b = a;

    a.Add("1");
    b.Add("2");

    Console.WriteLine(a.Count().ToString() + " " + a[0]);
    Console.WriteLine(b.Count().ToString() + " " + b[0]);

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Вот не рабочий пример:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<string> a = new List<string>();
    ObservableCollection<string> b = new ObservableCollection<string>(a);

    a.Add("1");
    b.Add("2");

    Console.WriteLine(a.Count().ToString() + " " + a[0]);
    Console.WriteLine(b.Count().ToString() + " " + b[0]);

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

**Резюме:**

Во втором варианте каждая переменная выводит только свои значения, в отличии от первого варианта, где каждая переменная выводит все значения.

**Проблема:**

Мне необходимо передать ссылку List'а ObservableCollection'у и получать все значения List'а через ObservableCollection. Также в случае редактирования ObservableCollection, что бы редактировался List.

Проще говоря нужно в итоге получить первый вариант, но принимающая переменная должна быть ObservableCollection.

Очень не хотельсь бы городить что то большой через события и свойства.

**Вопросы:**

1. Почему это не работает?
2. Возможно ли передать переменной *ObservableCollection* ссылку на переменную *List*.
3. Возможно ли как-нибуть это вообще реализовать?

Comment: Возьмите здесь прокси-вариант ObservableCollection: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/670552/218063

Comment: А что мешает работать с одной ObservableCollection? Зачем держать две дублирующихся сущности?

Comment: Структура `ObservableCollection` шире чем `List`. `ObservableCollection` частично включает в себя `List` и `ObservableCollection` биндится в WPF, `List` (де)сериализуется в файл.

Comment: @Kirill ну и что вам мешает сериализовать в файл ObservableCollection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Не работает потому что это разные экземпляры.

Как уже ответил Igor:

В первом случае `List b` лишь ссылается на `List a`, поэтому по сути в обоих случаях вы работаете с **одним** экземпляром списка, куда добавляете и откуда выводите.

Во втором, `ObsevableCollection b` и `List a` имеют свои независимые экземпляры, а инициализируя, как это делаете вы, в `b` лишь копируются текущие элементы `a`. Причём нужно понимать, что для структур идёт копирование, а для классов лишь ссылка на экземляр копируется.

2. Ссылку передать нельзя. В реализации этих классов такой функции нет.
3. В вашем случае нельзя.

Причина проста: `List` не имеет возможности хоть как-то уведомлять об изменении. Даже если вы захотите написать какой-то свой класс, то вы просто не сможете узнавать, изменился ли `List` или нет.

Что именно вы хотите реализовать не совсем понятно, поэтому подсказать трудно, но может в данном случае помочь [BindingList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms132679.aspx). Уже с ним вы сможете написать свой класс, который будет связывать `ObsevableCollection` и `BindingList`, но опять же - базовой реализации нет.

Дополнение:

Если очень хочется и ObservableCollection и List, то пишите отдельный метод:

```
List<string> a = new List<string>();
ObservableCollection<string> b = new ObservableCollection<string>();

void Add(string newstring)
{
   a.Add(newstring);
   b.Add(newstring);
}
```

Можно и отдельный класс для этого написать, где будут все основные команды присутствовать (Clear, Remove, Insert). Но тогда все изменения нужно будет проводить **только** через этот вспомогательный класс. И если вдруг какой-нибудь из списков изменится где-нибудь не в этом классе, то об этом вы уже не узнаете.

Comment: В прицепе не в чем, кроме того, что мало опыта в C#. :) Поэтому опасаюсь, что не будут работать некоторые моменты, корорые я написал в коментарии к @Igor.

Comment: И не совсем понял вот это: "...Причём нужно понимать, что для структур идёт копирование, а для классов лишь ссылка на экземляр копируется."?

Comment: @Kirill а что не понятного? это же основа основ) Если структура, то копируется полностью вся структура, если класс, то копируется ссылка на экземпляр класса. https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/

Comment: Обёртка над List .add и тд, которая будет хранить состояние изменений. Но это грубо и велосипедного совсем.

Comment: @John да, это я понимаю, но насколько я знаю упомянутые выше классы это именно **class**, а не **struct**. И поскольку **class**, в отличие **struct**, является ссылочным типом данных и я не могу понять почему нельзя передать ссылку. Единственное предположение, что они не наследуемые друг от друга, но это я думаю непроблема и она должна решаться путем написания раширения для обоих классов, если это позволяет Microsoft. Вот такова моя логика, я конечно же могу ошибаться т.к. мало опыта на C#.

Comment: @Kirill мы видимо друг друга не поняли. Я говорю не про сами списки, а их элементы. Именно они копируются, как класс или структура, при `new ObservableCollection<string>(a)`. Что касаемо наследование, то это можно узнать из MSDN. ObsevableCollection наследуется от Collection, в то же время List наследуется напрямую от Object.

Comment: @John Все я Вас понял выимеете ввиду, что у меня `string` , Хотя он и относится к сылочным типам (но не простым, не помню название), но все равно копируется как int, bool... вобщем как типы значений. Спасибо, что помогли разобраться.

Answer (score 2):

> где каждая переменная выводит все значения.

Потому что в первом примере `a` и `b` ссылаются на один и тот же объект.

Bторой пример аналогичен не

```
List<string> a = new List<string>();
List<string> b = a;
```

а

```
List<string> a = new List<string>();
List<string> b = new List<string>(a);
```

где `a` и `b` разные списки, которые ничего не знают о добавлении элементов друг в друга.

Вас не устроит общий интерфейс `ICollection<T>`?

Comment: Вы хотите сказать, что необходимо просто `List` и `ObservableCollection` заменить на `ICollection`?

Comment: @Kirill Да, слева в декларациях. И не создавать второй объект.

Comment: Я полагаю у меня не должно быть проблем с сериализацией в файл? Просто `List` а сеарилизую/десирилизую в файл, а `ObservableCollection` бинжу на WPF. `ObservableCollection` - шире чем `List`.